# iPhone simulator screen resolution vs iPhone screen resolution

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator

I'm pretty new to iOS developing and I have this stupid question. I have a pic 64 pixels width. And iPhone 5 simulator screen width is 320 pixels and on the simulator it takes 20% of the screen width. But I know that real iPhone screen width is 640 pixels. Does it mean that my picture will take 10% of the screen width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objective-C:

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

Swift:

```
let screenBounds:CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
```

That will give you the entire screen's resolution in points, so it would most typically be 320x480 for **older** iPhones. Even though the **iPhone 4** has a much larger screen size iOS still gives back 320x480 instead of 640x960.

For **iPhone 6+/7+**, it is 414x736 (native bounds: 1242*2208)

For **iPhone 6/7**, it is 375x667 (native bounds: 750x1334)

You can check "**native bounds**" by changing `bounds` to `nativeBounds` in the above code

Objective-C:

```
CGFloat screenScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

Swift:

```
let screenScale:CGFloat = UIScreen.main.scale
```

This will give you the scale of the screen. For all devices that do not have Retina Displays this will return a 1.0f, while Retina Display devices will give a 2.0f and the iPhone 6 Plus (Retina HD) will give a 3.0f.

Now if you want to get the pixel width & height of the iOS device screen you just need to do one simple thing.

```
CGSize screenSize = CGSizeMake(screenBounds.size.width * screenScale, screenBounds.size.height * screenScale);
```

By multiplying by the screen's scale you get the actual pixel resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Everything on the simulator looks exactly as it will look on the device. Otherwise, the simulator would be rather pointless, don't you think so?

On all iOS devices, you need to distinguish between **points** and **pixels**. You do all your calculations and all your graphics commands in points. The iPhone 5 has 320 x 568 points. Each point is displayed using 2 x 2 pixels to get better image quality. But if you want to draw something covering the whole screen, that would be 320 x 568 points, and that's what you use in your software. 99.9% of the time, iOS handles the difference for you.